# Updating Service Principle Password with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Updating a service principles password with Terraform based on when it's going to expire

Setting the service principle up with a password the first time works perfectly, however, I want to expire the password and if the password is going to expire a new one gets generated and updates the service principle with it, I'm not entirely sure how to do conditionals in Terraform as I am still fairly new to Terraform, the docs don't really talk about updating the service principle only creating it and there is no data object to fetch when this is going to expire

So far I have this (full disclosure this is part of a bigger terraform base that I am helping with):

```
resource "azuread_application" "current" {
  name = "test"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "current" {
  application_id = "${azuread_application.current.application_id}"
}

resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 64
  special = true
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "current" {
  service_principal_id = "${azuread_service_principal.current.id}"
  value                = "${random_string.password.result}"
  end_date_relative    = "2160h"   # valid for 90 days
}
```

As the password is only valid for 90 Days I want to run terraform apply just before it expires and update the password

### Update 1:

It seems that if indeed you change the `azuread_service_principal_password` resource, it counts as a change in the dependency tree and recreates the resource you have attached the service principle to, which means there is no way to keep the state in of the service principles credentials in Terraform if they need to be updates

### Update 2:

I have attempted to do the following, however the downside to this is that it runs everytime you run terraform apply:

terraform script:

```
resource "azuread_application" "current" {
  name = "${var.metadata_name}"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "current" {
  application_id = "${azuread_application.current.application_id}"
}
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 64
  special = true
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "current" {
  service_principal_id = "${azuread_service_principal.current.id}"
  value                = "${random_string.password.result}"
  end_date_relative    = "2160h"                                   # valid for 90 days
}


resource "null_resource" "password_updater" {
  # Updates everytime you run terraform apply so it will run this script everytime
  triggers {
    timestamp = "${timestamp()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sh ${path.module}/update_service_password.sh ${azuread_service_principal.current.id} ${var.resource_group} ${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.current.name}"
  }
}
```

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
service_principle_id=$1
resource_group=$2
cluster_name=$3

# get service password expiration
expiration=$(az ad sp list --filter="objectId eq '$service_principle_id'" | jq '.[].passwordCredentials' | jq '.[].endDate' | cut -d'T' -f 1 | cut -d'"' -f 2)

# Format date for condition
now=$(date  +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
expiration_date=$(date -d "$expiration - 30 days"  +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)


# Compare today with expiration date
if [ ${now} -ge ${expiration_date} ];
then
    # IF expiration date in the next 30 days rest password
    sp_id=$(az aks show -g ${resource_group} -n ${cluster_name} --query servicePrincipalProfile.clientId -o tsv)
    service_principle_secret=$(az ad sp credential reset --name ${sp_id} --end-date $(date -d "+ 90 days"  +%Y-%m-%d) --query password -o tsv)

    # Update cluster with new password
    az aks update-credentials \
    --resource-group ${resource_group} \
    --name ${cluster_name} \
    --reset-service-principal \
    --service-principal ${sp_id} \
    --client-secret ${service_principle_secret}
fi
```

Comment: All the ideas i have involve some sort of manual interaction, especially since you state "there is no data object to fetch when this is going to expire". I think you might have to write some sort of local script to determine when the password expired to trigger the Terraform logic. Alternatively, you could PR against the Azure provider or make a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just going to set this as the Answer as after talking to the developers of the service principle terraform module they have told me it is not possible any other way if, a better way is found please comment:

Answer:

Use the null_resource provider to run a script that runs the update -

```
resource "azuread_application" "current" {
  name = "${var.metadata_name}"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "current" {
  application_id = "${azuread_application.current.application_id}"
}
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 64
  special = true
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "current" {
  service_principal_id = "${azuread_service_principal.current.id}"
  value                = "${random_string.password.result}"
  end_date_relative    = "2160h"                                   # valid for 90 days
}


resource "null_resource" "password_updater" {
  # Updates everytime you run terraform apply so it will run this script everytime
  triggers {
    timestamp = "${timestamp()}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sh ${path.module}/update_service_password.sh ${azuread_service_principal.current.id} ${var.resource_group} ${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.current.name}"
  }
}
```

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
service_principle_id=$1
resource_group=$2
cluster_name=$3

# get service password expiration
expiration=$(az ad sp list --filter="objectId eq '$service_principle_id'" | jq '.[].passwordCredentials' | jq '.[].endDate' | cut -d'T' -f 1 | cut -d'"' -f 2)

# Format date for condition
now=$(date  +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
expiration_date=$(date -d "$expiration - 30 days"  +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)


# Compare today with expiration date
if [ ${now} -ge ${expiration_date} ];
then
    # IF expiration date in the next 30 days rest password
    sp_id=$(az aks show -g ${resource_group} -n ${cluster_name} --query servicePrincipalProfile.clientId -o tsv)
    service_principle_secret=$(az ad sp credential reset --name ${sp_id} --end-date $(date -d "+ 90 days"  +%Y-%m-%d) --query password -o tsv)

    # Update cluster with new password
    az aks update-credentials \
    --resource-group ${resource_group} \
    --name ${cluster_name} \
    --reset-service-principal \
    --service-principal ${sp_id} \
    --client-secret ${service_principle_secret}
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

For the service principal, the password of it can be reset through the Azure CLI [`az ad sp reset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#reset-credentials), but you need to have the permission to do that.

Comment: This will only work if I am manually running it, this Terraform script handles bigger infrastructure and I don't want the service principle's password expiring while trying to run the rest of it, so running it manually won't work for this use case

Comment: @Spazzy757 But it seems you cannot reset the password through Terraform.

Comment: why not? you just change the password on the `azuread_service_principal_password` and it will get changed

Comment: I was thinking of maybe using Terraforms external plugin to run a script but this is a bit of a hack so I wanted to know if there was any terraform native way to handle this

Comment: How would you handle the logic of updating only if about to expire though?

Comment: you cant handle that logic, terraform is not aware of that

Comment: so maybe running a bash script to do that logic in a data object?

Comment: azuread_service_principal_password is not even exposed as a data object

Comment: @4c74356b41 It's my mistake.

Comment: @Spazzy757 You can reset the service principal password through many methods. But how can you do it automately? I don't think it's a good way. My suggestion is that you can delay its expire time. It's easy and just need to do one time.

Comment: I am working on a solution using the external data resource that handles the logic in a shell script, but still a bit hacky so still hoping for a cleaner solutions

Comment: @Spazzy757 OK, if you use the terraform external data then I can provide more bits of help, but the problem is how do you check the expiry date? every time?

Comment: Currently yes, it seems that every time I run terraform apply I will need to check the expiry date, I can't really see any way around it because of the dependency, will post the start of my solutions later today and maybe we can discuss from there?

Answer (score -1):

I think a better approach is this:

1. Your terraform code is most likely wrapped within a bigger process. Most likely you use bash to kick off the process and then terraform. If not - I suggest you do it as this is the best practice with terraform.
2. In your bash code before running terraform check the expiry of the relevant service principals using az cli, for example. (does not matter)
3. If expired, use the [terraform taint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/taint.html) command to mark the service principal password resources as tainted. I do not have the details, maybe you need to taint the service principal too. Maybe not.
4. If tainted, the terraform would recreate the resources and would regenerate the password.

Comment: I’m not really sure that wrapping something in bash is best practice? That goes against the ideologies of declarative infrastructure as it is by nature imperative?

Comment: The infrastructure code is all in terraform and all declarative. But terraform is lacking some features vital in a big project. BTW, if you store terraform state in cloud (as you should), then what does create that storage? We have an chicken and the egg situation here. Terraform is not ready to occupy 100% of the infrastructure code. Checkout terragrunt - it exemplifies what I mean.

Comment: If you're using enterprise you don't have the chicken and egg problem? Also adding another technology to the stack is the complete last thing I would ever want to do.

Comment: Have you had a look at terragrunt? They make it very clear why this is needed. We are not using terragrunt but we also think that terraform alone is not enough. There is more to infrastructure deployment than just the bare infrastructure code. Terraform 0.14 alone is just not enough.

Comment: I disagree, yes I’ve looked terragrunt, I’m not a fan.

Comment: Small example. How do you load terraform modules from a different git version from that recorded in the version control? E.g. you want to test changes from a branch? Terraform does not have first class support for macros. You cannot parameterize module source. What would you do? Change the source code every time you need to test a remote module from a branch? Another example - we use Azure backend for TF state. When invoking TF someone needs to prepare the  backend parameters which in our case depend on the pod being deployed. And we have tens of pods. How to deal with it in pure terraform?

Comment: I think if you want to have this argument you should go to a forum. Your solution does not solve my problem. You have solved a problem with terragrunt that I do not have. None of this is very valid.